# Firejail+Apparmor change profile from firejail-default

Tags: apparmor

i recently installed Firejail on my Ubuntu.
It says it has an Apparmor support, which i am already using.

After the setup of Firejail, i made some profile files in Firejail.

When i run `firejail --apparmor firefox`, Firejail loads the certain profile of firefox.

But Apparmor is loading the `firejail-default` profile.

Is there a way to tell apparmor to load my old already existing apparmor-profile of firefox instead of firejail-default.

So that both are loading their firefox profile, not only one of them.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you [have to](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/blob/master/src/firejail/sandbox.c#L1195) patch it.